# Change Xcode BundleID and project name from ReactNative Project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-developer

A while ago I started a React Native project which generated the Xcode project folder/files including an unwanted bundleID, project name and target names etc.

When I try to create an app in AppStoreConnect or APNs Certificate in my Apple Developer account the bundleID of this app does not appear in the list, probably because I did not start the project in Xcode.

I need to change the bundleID and ideally the project name/target name etc, but the existing names are tied-up in the wider repository and cause errors.

This, two questions;

1. Should I make the changes in Xcode or somewhere in the VScode repo?
2. How can I get my bundleID to show in my Apple Developer account?

Many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

You can use this plugin to rename your app.

And your have to create your bundle id in:
Apple developer -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers